# is it possible Customise FullCalendar with css in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I just begin with FullCalendar , i'm implementing it in a **react** project , everything good now but i want to customize the actual calendar , iwant it to respect my customer need.

My question : is it possible to add a **classname** to the FullCalendar component like this : 
( i tried but i can't reach the classname in my css file )

```
                <FullCalendar
                  className= "FullCalendarMonthClient"
                  defaultView= "dayGridMonth"
                  plugins={[dayGridPlugin]} 
                  columnHeaderFormat= {{                    
                    weekday: "long"
                  }} 
                  locale="fr"
                  events={[
                    { title: 'event 1', start: '2019-12-06', end: '2019-12-07' },
                    { title: 'event 1', start: '2019-12-06', end: '2019-12-07' }
                  ]}
                />
```

and after use it to customize my calendar with css. I use on the same page an other calendar , a DayView that why i ask to put a classname in my component so i can style my dayview/monthview without touching  the Monthview. Or how can i create my own theme ?

Thanks comunity

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theming talks about theming. The easiest way to create your own is probably to copy the code of the default theme and then alter whichever bits you need to.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a styled wrapper that will overwrite the internal styles.

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";


export const StyleWrapper = styled.div`
  .fc td {
    background: red;
  }
`


const MyApp = ()=> {
  return (
    <StyleWrapper>
      <FullCalendar/>
    </StyleWrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, a styled wrapper works. For example, try changing the buttons (next, prev) in the Calendar:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';

// needed for the style wrapper
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

// add styles as css
export const StyleWrapper = styled.div`
  .fc-button.fc-prev-button, .fc-button.fc-next-button, .fc-button.fc-button-primary{
    background: red;
    background-image: none;
}
`

// component with calendar, surround the calendar with the StyleWrapper
function Schedule({ ...props }) {
  return (
    <StyleWrapper>
                      <FullCalendar ... />
    </StyleWrapper>
  );
}

export default Schedule;
```

Comment: Is there another way to change the styling?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using @fullcalendar/react with @fullcalendar/bootstrap and @fullcalendar/rrule YOU NEED TO CHECK YOUR IMPORTS.
I have having an issue where the rrulePlugin was over-riding my bootstrap theme, It was the way I was importing.

Import in this order solved it for me

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Col, Row} from 'reactstrap';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';



  <div>
        <CardBody className="p-0">
     
          <FullCalendar
            ref={calendarRef}
            headerToolbar={false}
            plugins={[ // plugins MUST be in this order for mine to work or else I get errors
              rrulePlugin,
              dayGridPlugin,
              bootstrapPlugin,
              timeGridPlugin,
              interactionPlugin,
              listPlugin,
                  ]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            themeSystem="bootstrap"
            dayMaxEvents={2}
            height={800}
            stickyHeaderDates={false}
            editable
            selectable
            selectMirror
            select={info => {
              console.log("calendarInfo", info.start.toISOString())
              if(info.start < moment().subtract(1, 'day')) {
                toast(
                  <Fragment>
                    <strong>Select Future date</strong>
                  </Fragment>
                );
              } else if(isCompose) {
                return (calendarView === "Month View" ? setShowTimeModal(!showTimeModal) : ""),
                setAddScheduleStartDate(info.start.toString())
              } else {
              setAddScheduleStartDate(info.start.toISOString());
              setIsOpenScheduleModal(true);
            }
          
            }}
            views={views}
            eventTimeFormat={eventTimeFormat}
            eventClick={handleEventClick}
            events={calendar}
            buttonText={buttonText}
            eventDrop={(e) => { return console.log("eventDrop ran======-----======", dispatch(calendarUpdate({start: e.event.start, end: e.event.end, _id: e.event._def.extendedProps._id})))}}
          />
       
        </CardBody>
        </div>
```