# FullCalendar timeGridPlugin is not working after I add a styled wrapper from emotion/styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, emotion

I am using FullCalendar and wanted to modify some of the styles within the component. I'm implementing it in a react project, but once I added the styled wrapper that will overwrite the internal styles my calendar loses the timeGridPlugin and does not show any times.

I followed this StackOverflow post already: [is it possible Customise FullCalendar with css in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177150/is-it-possible-customise-fullcalendar-with-css-in-react)

A condensed version of my code:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import FullCalendar, { formatDate } from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
```

```
export const StyleWrapper = styled.div`
  .fc-toolbar-title {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

```
render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          padding: "2em",
          fontFamily: `'Quicksand', sans-serif`,
        }}
        data-testid="FullCalender"
      >
        <StyleWrapper>
          <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            headerToolbar={{
              start: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              end: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
            }}
            initialView="timeGridWeek"
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={true}
            select={this.handleSelectSlot}
            eventClick={this.handleSelectEvent}
            eventDrop={this.handleEventDrop}
            height={"90%"}
          />
        </StyleWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My question: How to add styling without affecting the timeGridPlugin?

When I comment out <StyleWrapper></StyleWrapper>, then the timeGridPlugin works: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgdYX.png)

With StyleWrapper: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/imzWv.png)